# vscode jquery auto completion on certain file

Tags: jquery, settings, laravel-blade, visual-studio-code

I know that the new VSCode enable us to get jquery autocompletion within `<script>` in HTML files. The question is, how to enable it on another file extension such as blade.php? FYI, I'm using VSCode for Linux.

Comment: visit [**here**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php)

Comment: that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for how to enable jquery autocompletion on blade.php files which has no relation to PHP files (they are treated differently by vscode). But thanks anyway :) @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: sorry, are you using `npm` ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam sometimes yes but sometimes not. But that makes no difference for me. It still shows jquery autocompletion for me (whether I use `npm` or not) when I try it on HTML script tag. This is what I looking for (but instead on blade.php file): [check here](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/16159685/22621542/19470d34-eaf4-11e6-84a9-28ae0a975da5.png)